# Get Value from within a Function - Bootstrap-Slider

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-slider

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Receive both the Height & Weight values from the [Bootstrap-Sliders](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) and use these values to work out the BMI.

**Current Problems:**
Unable to get both the Height & Weight values from within each function due to the `.change` event.

Open to suggestions and advice,
Thank you!

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  // Weight
  $('#weight').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return value;
    }
  }).on('slideStop', function(ev){
     $(this).val($(this).data('slider').getValue());
  });
  $('#weight').change(function() {
    var weightval = $('#weight').val();
  });
  // Height
  $('#height').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Height: ' + value;
    }
  }).on('slideStop', function(ev){
     $(this).val($(this).data('slider').getValue());
  });
  $('#height').change(function() {
    var heightval = $('#height').val();
  });
  // BMI
  $('#bmi').text(weightval + heightval);
});
```

**JS** - Also Tried.

```
  var heightval;
  $('#height').change(function() {
    heightval = $('#height').val();
  });
  $('#bmi').text(heightval);
```

**HTML**

```
    <input id="weight" data-slider-id='weightSlider' type="text" data-slider-min="50" data-slider-max="150" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0"/>
    <input id="height" data-slider-id='heightSlider' type="text" data-slider-min="100" data-slider-max="250" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0"/>
```

**JS** - Anwser

```
$(function() {
  // Weight
  $('#weight').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return value;
    }
  }).on('slideStop', function(ev){
     $(this).val($(this).data('slider').getValue());
  });
  $('#weight').change(updateBmi);
  // Height
  $('#height').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Height: ' + value;
    }
  }).on('slideStop', function(ev){
     $(this).val($(this).data('slider').getValue());
  });
  $('#height').change(updateBmi);

  function updateBmi(){
    var heightval = $('#height').val(); // Height
    var weightval = $('#weight').val(); // Weight
    var bmicalc = (weightval/heightval)/heightval; // BMI Calc
    var bmi = Math.round(bmicalc * 10) / 10; // Decimal
    $('#bmi').text(bmiround); // Display Value
  }
});
```

**Live URL**
[RawGit](https://rawgit.com/adamkwadsworth/Livingwise/master/index.html)

Comment: You are declaring every `variable` inside inside particular `event` which are not accessible and you might get `undefined`. So declare all the variables outside `globally` + add some `html` too to understand clearly..

Comment: Haven't I declared the veritable outside the event - see JS V2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I got the question right (if not, please post a jsfiddle or jsbin sample), I think you can use a single handler for the change:

```
$('#weight').change(updateBmi);
$('#height').change(updateBmi);  

function updateBmi(){
    var heightval = $('#height').val();
    var weightval = $('#weight').val();
    $('#bmi').text(weightval + heightval);
}
```

Comment: Afternoon Meir, I noticed when sliding/changing the range multiple times the values seem to break and display the wrong answers! 

e.g Weight 16, Height 1 should be 16! This works the first time but If you change either the Weight and Height to another value then back to 16, 1 the values changes! sometimes it says infinity sometimes it says 4, or some random long string of numbers!!!! I have uploaded the project onto Git - https://github.com/adamkwadsworth/Livingwise let me know if you can help!

Comment: Hi Adam. The infinity is due to a division by 0:
    var bmicalc = weightval/eval(heightval*heightval); // BMI Calculation
either ensure that the height is greater than 0 or set a reasonable minimum for height. See if this still happens after that.
As for the wrong values, it might be due to event timing. I suggest inside your updateBmi method you do:
setTimeout(function(){
// enter all logic here
}, 10);
This will ensure all event loop is finished before the calculation is performed.

Comment: Sorry, I published the comment half way through, I think now it has the answers. In general JS is an event based single threaded runtime, so you might get strange results if the update order is wrong. The timeout of 10 (mSec) executes the evaluation only once all updates are done. In general, a timeout of 0 is enough since it schedules your code to the next event cycle.

Comment: Thank you for this Meir, I really appreciate the extra help!

Comment: Gladly, but now the tension is killing me :-) Did it work as expected? Are all the problems solved?

Comment: Trying to figure out the NaN/Infinity issues! Apart from this everything seems to work! I've updated the Git folder of you want to have a nosey at it! :)

Comment: The NaN/Infinity is due to a division by zero. Make sure you height is at least 1, read my previous comments :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90401/discussion-between-adamkwadsworth-and-meir).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at following code:

```
$(function() {
  // Weight
  var weightSlider = $('#weight').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return value;
    }
  }).on('slideStop', function(ev){
     calculateBMI();
  });

  // Height
  var heightSlider = $('#height').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Height: ' + value;
    }
  }).on('slideStop', function(ev){
     calculateBMI();
  });

  function calculateBMI(){
      // BMI
      var weightSelected = weightSlider.getValue();
      var heightSelected = heightSlider.getValue();
      $('#bmi').text(weightSelected + heightSelected );
  }
});
```

No need to go for `.change` event

Comment: I've implemented the above but get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: a.getValue is not a function